# Persist custom class into database, custom serialization rules

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have this class

```
public class Money {
   private BigDecimal amount;
   private String currency;
}
```

I would like, by creating a custom serializator or similar ways, to tell hibernate to persist the `Money` class as `String` in this way: **23.00 EUR**

Basically the serialization will be `amount` rounded with 2 decimals + space + `currency`, and the deserialization will follow the inverse logic.

It shouldn't be difficult to implement, but I couldn't find hints.
Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ready to go:    [AttributeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html)

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;


@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class MoneyAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Money, String> {
    
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Money in) {
        return ... convert here;
    }

    @Override
    public Money  convertToEntityAttribute(String in) {
        return ... and here;
    }
}
```

Hope helpul :)

EDIT. Note on the margin, serialisation is 'similar' to persistence, but not the same. Google in the net "differences between `@Transient` annotation and `transient` keyword"

Comment: Exaclty what I was looking for. I know the difference, thanks :)