# Which variables use in JavaFX/Hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

Let's say we got a `Entity/Class` Person which I want to populate in TableView in JavaFX component.

What type of data should I populate Person class - `String` or `SimpleStringProperty`?

In both cases I dont get fully what I want. If I will use String variable I won't be able to listen to any changes done in my TableView (according to post [clickMe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381067/simplestringproperty-and-simpleintegerproperty-tableview-javafx)). On the other hand if I will use `SimpleStringProperty` I will get and Exception that hibernate can't convert `SimpleStringProperty` into String which is the type being used in database. How can it be done more cleverly?

```
@Entity
public Person {
    private String name;     // or SimpleStringProperty
    private String Surname; // or SimpleStringProperty

    // getter and setters removed to simplify example
}
```

Comment: Use `StringProperty` and use property access (not field access) in Hibernate. http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa.html

Comment: you could just tell Hibernate how to make a SimpleStringProperty into a String? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869207/persist-custom-class-into-database-custom-serialization-rules and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048978/convert-list-in-entity-to-single-string-column-in-database

Comment: @Jeutnarg That looks like overkill. Just make sure it uses the `get/set` methods instead of trying to set the fields directly.

Comment: @James_D will that work with SimpleStringProperty (which has get/setValue, not get/set)? If so, could you link in something that shows how to tell property access to use the getValue and setValue methods?

Comment: @Jeutnarg I was assuming the OP was following the standard pattern, i.e. `public StringProperty nameProperty()`, `public String getName()`, `public void setName(String name)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `StringProperty`, and ensure that Hibernate accesses the property via the `get/set` methods, not via the field itself. (This is referred to using "Property Access", as opposed to "Field Access".) If you make sure that all annotations are placed on the *methods*, not the fields, this will happen automatically, or you can use `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` to make it explicit:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty surname = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @Column("name") // not needed, just illustrating the annotations, if needed, go here
    public String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        nameProperty().get(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

See http://svanimpe.be/blog/properties-jpa.html for a complete discussion.

Comment: we don't need to implement Serializable interface, because it shows me warning : an Entity or IdClass class should implement serializable interface.